# Mypy reports error when I assign List[int] to List[float] or assign Dict[str, int] to Dict[str, float]

Tags: python, mypy

```
    a: List[float]
    c = [1,2]
    a = c
    b: Dict[str, float]
    d = {"1": 1, "2": 2}
    b = d
```

Is there a way to make the assignment legal other than using `Sequence` and `Mapping` instead of `List` and `Dict`

Comment: No, because it is not legal, because mutable containers are invariant.

Comment: I mean maybe methods like using `TypeVar` to define a type containing `int` and `float`?

Comment: you could use a union, I guess

Comment: You can `cast`.

Comment: `a: List[Union[int, float]]` ?

Comment: A `List[float]` allows appending floats to it. A `List[int]` does not. If `a = c` were legal, you could do `a.append(3.0)`, and then `c` would be a `List[int]` with a float in it.

Comment: `a: List[Union[int, float]]` won't do the trick